# ImageLoader is not giving right dimensions

Tags: android, imageview

I'm using the class `ImageLoader` to load an image from the internet, but when i want to get the width and the height of the photo, it gives me width:1 and height:1. The imageloader is the imageloader from here: [ImageLoader](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/)

Call method and calculate dimensions:

```
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(url, R.drawable.thumbnail_background, image);

        // Change params
        image.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo); 
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollLayout);



                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                int newWidth = size.x;

                int orgWidth = image.getWidth();
                int orgHeight = image.getHeight();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(newWidth) + " - " + Integer.toString(orgWidth) + " - " + Integer.toString(orgHeight), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();


                int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(newWidth / (orgWidth / orgHeight));


                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    newWidth, newHeight);
                //image.setLayoutParams(params);
                image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                layout.updateViewLayout(image, params);      
             }  
            });
        }
```

Comment: maybe your layout height is not enough

Comment: @MoshErsan Which layout? The imageview itself or it's parent?

Comment: its parent has `wrap_content` as height

Comment: no, set it to match_parent, and so the imageview

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the original size of the image:

```
image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight()
image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()
```

Comment: `orgWidth` and `orgHeight` become -1 now

Answer (score 0):

you can inflate this layout, and get a reference to `ImageView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/my_imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: still half of the height, image looks squashed now